# How can we divide two tools into microservices which talks over stdin stdout

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

I have few set of tools which communicate with each other visa stdin/stdout/stderr.
I want to divide them up into separate microservices. I want to let them feel as if they are still communication over command line stdin/stdout.

How can I make the communications between the tools over microservices?

We cannot reengineer the tools and architecture until some time, so need to solve this as it is.

Answer (score 1):

> I have few set of tools which communicate with each other visa stdin/stdout/stderr.

Tools can communicate over stdin/stdout/stderr. But...

> I want to divide them up into separate microservices. I want to let them feel as if they are still communication over command line stdin/stdout.

*Microservices* should communicate over network - so they are *loosely coupled*. This is a fundamental thing about Microservices.

You essentially have to rearchitect so that the communicate over some for of network protocol or use messaging like e.g. Kafka.

Comment: I am aware about microservices architecture, but this is the problem need to solve as it is.

Comment: So they are not microservices since they do not communicate over network.

Comment: I mean somehow I can add a wrapper so that they can communicate via network